# Upload de imagem direto no BD MySql utilizando C#

Tags: c#, mysql, imagem, upload, asp

Estou criando uma aplicação WEB utilizando C# e um BD MySql.
Preciso fazer o upload de uma imagem no Banco e depois recupera-la.

Sou iniciante nesse mundo, mas o que tenho até o momento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um campo `fupCPF` que recebe a imagem, depois executo o Insert abaixo:

```
string comando = "SELECT imagem_cpf FROM tb_cpf WHERE id_usuario=@loginUsuario";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(comando, mConn);

string comando = "INSERT INTO tb_cpf (id_usuario, numero, imagem_cpf) VALUES (@id_usuario, @numero, @imagem_cpf)";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(comando, conexao);
//preenchimento dos parâmetros
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_usuario", emailUsuario);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numero", txtCodCPF.Text.ToString());

byte[] imageBytes = new byte[fupCPF.PostedFile.InputStream.Length + 1];
fupCPF.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagem_cpf", imageBytes);
conexao.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conexao.Close();

lblImgCPFErro.Text = "INSERIDO COM SUCESSO!!";
```

Eu insiro algo no banco (um arquivo .bin) mas não sei como testar se está funcionando... Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Criei uma página para visualização, no page_Load tem o seguinte código (depois da conexão com o Banco)

```
string comando = "SELECT imagem_cpf FROM tb_cpf WHERE id_usuario=@loginUsuario";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(comando, mConn);

//preenchimento dos parâmetros
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginUsuario", loginUsuario);
mConn.Open();

MySqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (myReader.Read())
{
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
   Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])myReader["imagem_cpf"]);

}

myReader.Close();
mConn.Close();
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: É necessário salvar a imagem no banco de dados? Eu salvaria em uma pasta dentro do servidor e salvaria somente o caminho da imagem.

Comment: Bom dia Marlon, poderia ser sim.. mas não faço idéia de como fazer isso...

Comment: no caso vai ter que fazer upload no servidor, ai depois você vai pegar o caminho resultante e salvar como campo de texto normal... melhor forma

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço em Pasta normalmente para não sobrecarregar o banco de dados, apesar de já ter feito isto e caso precise posso buscar em meus projetos antigos.

Abaixo um trecho do fonte no qual faço upload em meu projeto atual

```
if (Request.Files["Arquivo" ] != null && Request.Files["Arquivo" ].FileName != "")
            {
                veiculoOcorrenciaAnexoViewModel.NomeArquivo = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files["Arquivo" ].FileName);
                string path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Arquivos\\Veiculos\\Ocorrencias\\" + veiculoOcorrenciaAnexoViewModel.VeiculoOcorrenciaId + "\\" ;
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

                Request.Files["Arquivo" ].SaveAs(path + veiculoOcorrenciaAnexoViewModel.NomeArquivo);
                _vOcorrenciaAnexoAppService.Adicionar(veiculoOcorrenciaAnexoViewModel);    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá viva como já indicaram a melhor prática é guardar as imagens na pasta publica no servidor ou num blob storage.

Partilho detalhes adicionais, para comparar com base na minha experiência:

**DB**

O armazenamento de blob na base de dados irá fazer com que a dimensão do armazenamento aumente consideravelmente, estive envolvido num projeto que por uma opção de arquitetura, era assim efetuado e essa mesma tabela em poucos meses cresceu para os 100GB, solução separar a tabela das imagens para outra DB, ficando a db core em 3/4 GB, imagina todos os dias era efetuado um backup, o que obrigava a uma estratégia de otimização de espaço em disco, e tinha de ser bem definido a estratégia para um restore por exemplo, uma vez que 100GB é bem diferente de 3/4GB. Em suma, esta arquitetura, imagem guardada na base de dados, funciona, mas não é a melhor a abordagem pelos problemas/constrangimentos que enumerei entre outros, por exemplo, por vezes pediam imagens de determinado registo para analisar, tinha de ser extraído com um SW e gerar um PDF por exemplo, enquanto que se fosse um blob storage, bastaria partilhar o path da imagem original.

**Blob Sorage**

Por exemplo com technologias Microsoft, [blob storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/visual-studio/vs-storage-aspnet-getting-started-blobs), e guardar na base de dados somente o caminho (path) da imagem. Podes utilizar para aceder, existem tools para o efeito, verifica [aqui](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

Em alternativa existe o Bucket da AWS, o S3, tens documentação [aqui](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpNET.html).